# How can I disable Mac OS X's Option+click hiding behaviour?

Tags: macos

In Mac OS X Mountain Lion at least, if you <kbd>Option</kbd>+click ( <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click ) on another a window of another app, this will make the other application to gain focus, and the current app to be *hidden* as if you'd pressed <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour? Perhaps with some `defaults write` like command entered in a terminal?

I'd like to use <kbd>Option</kbd>+click for some different behaviour (moving windows by <kbd>Option</kbd>+clicking and dragging anywhere on them, using a third-party tool, Zoom2), and having <kbd>Option</kbd>+click trigger the hiding behaviour instead is very inconvenient.

Comment: You may be able to pass the option-click to a background window by also pressing command. If that actually works with your windowing-tool depends on how cleanly that is implemented.